# Why there is not Tomcat error page in Spring Boot 1.1.9.RELEASE

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.1.9.RELEASE with thymeleaf. If there some error in my code, the Tomcat default error page doesn't display. I have disabled the sample error page. Please see my application.yml file.

```
error: 
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false
```

Before 1.1.9.RELEASE, if I disable the whitelabel, the Tomcat error page will show. Is there any other config I need to do to show up the Tomat error page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `error.whitelable.enabled=false` ever worked that way. To switch off the Boot error handling you need to actually exclude the `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` in your `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: When I exclude the ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, it works. But I remember that, in the previous version of Boot, if we set whitelable to false, the default error page will display.